# how to implement social login in angular 15 application?

Tags: angular, angular-social-login

I am trying to implement social login in angular 15 application. suggest me how to do that?

I tried using angularx-social-login@4.0.1

Comment: Do some research on your own, try things out and if you're stuck at a specific problem, you come here and ask.

Comment: I tried using angularx-social-login@4.0.1 but its not working any alternative other than this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I tried using the @abacritt/angularx-social-login but its throwing an error Generic type 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration' requires between 6 and 8 type arguments.

15     static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<GoogleSigninButtonDirective, "asl-google-signin-button", never, { "type": "type"; "size": "size"; "text": "text"; "shape": "shape"; "theme": "theme"; "logo_alignment": "logo_alignment"; "width": "width"; "locale": "locale"; }, {}, never, never, false, never>;